# google maps api direction service ( multi routes & 30 waypoints)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm want to use google maps api for ( multi routes and 30 waypoints)

I have 3 drivers and 30 waypoints and I want to make three routes each route has 10 waypoints.

I want to optomize the routes to be best for each driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want your app to behave similarly to [this Google example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-waypoints).

Note that as per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#waypoint-limits), you can make up to 23 waypoints, plus the origin and the destination.

To optimize the routes, you can use the `optimizeWaypoints` field of the `DirectionsRequest` object which rearranges the waypoints in a more efficient order when it's set to `true`.

As a side-note I recommend you use [this tool](https://directionsdebug.firebaseapp.com/) as playground to test things out.

Hope this helps!